# Call a function from within another function in Python without using class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm stuck at calling one function from within other function. I know this question was asked many time here but I couldnt find the right answer.

Here's an example:

Make a function shout(word) that accepts a string and returns that string in capital letters.

```
def shout(word):

    return word.upper()

shout("bob")
```

Make a function introduce() to ask the user for their name and shout it back to them. Call your function shout to make this happen.

```
def introduce():

    name = input("What's your name: ")
    print(f"Hello {name}")

introduce()
```

My question is: How can I call shout() func from within introduce() func without using class? So the result looks like this:

```
What's your name?
Bob

HELLO BOB
```

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: Hm, wouldn't any 'hello world' python tutorial answer that?

Answer (score 0):

Just call function `shout`.

```
def shout(word):
    return word.upper()

def introduce():

    name = input("What's your name: ")
    name = shout(name)
    print(f"Hello {name}")

introduce()
```

Comment: This doesn't shout the `Hello` part.

Comment: Thank you very much, AgentDaun!

Answer (score 0):

You call functions from inside other functions the same way you call them from outside functions. Put the function name first, put the argument(s) in parentheses.

```
def introduce():

    name = input("What's your name: ")
    print(shout(f"Hello {name}"))
```

Comment: Great answer, this is what I was looking for. Thank you, Barmar.

Comment: This is really such a basic question, it suggests that you need to read programming tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call shout() function inside introduce():

```
def shout(word):
    return word.upper()

def introduce():
    name = input("What's your name: ")
    print(shout(f"Hello {name}")) << just like this.
```